# save url in MySql databse via PHP getting failed

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a array of URL which I am saving in database after iteration on PHP side.
I am sending the array with Ajax and saving it with PHP.

**Data send via Ajax**

```
linksString=http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=testdb&token=42d0dde57469a9aa4b6a2f7e0741,
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=testdb&token=98604a9aa4b6a2f7e0741,
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=testdb&token=9864dde57469a9aa4b6a2f7e0741,
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=testdb&token=986042d0dde57469a9aa4b6a2f7e0741,
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=testdb&token=986042d0dde57469a9a23&q=save
```

**Not getting all  values in $linksPieces , Getting only one value**

But I am not getting this all string in PHP side; only getting first sub string which is before first comma(,). 
I.E

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=testdb&token=42d0dde57469a9aa4b6a2f7e0741
```

**PHP**

```
$linksPieces = array();
$links =  $_POST['linksString'];
$linksPieces = explode(",", $links);
foreach($linksPieces as $link)
{
   //operation
}
```

I need to get all the string in array on PHP side.

If I am sending these type of url which have not any = then working fine.

```
http://in.yahoo.com/ 

http://www.hotmail.com/

http://www.google.com/

http://www.blah.com/

http://www.blah1.com/
```

Comment: What is not working fine ?  ,

Comment: Try to use when sending it from JS encodeURIComponent(str) and urldecode($_POST['linksString']) in PHP

Comment: Did you check to make sure the values are all there in '$links' (IE in $_POST) before you call explode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `encodeURIComponent()` in Javascript before sending this string and using `urldecode()` in PHP before using this string.